# Is this the proper use for multi-threading in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, multithreading, sprite-kit

So I have a game, and each level takes a lot of initialization and thus has a lag spike.

I have already broken the generation into multiple parts that each have a function.  Each function initialized a group of sprites and causes texture data loading etc.

Would this be a good idea to put each of these function on a separate thread then regroup afterwards?

Could this be achieved by the SKAction.group then SKAction.runBlock ? Would that achieve multi-threading?

Thanks much!

Comment: Not sure if multi-threading is going to help you out a lot here.  Are you using texture atlas's by chance? You could use multi-threading to display stuff while you are still loading in the background if you do not need everything loaded at once though, but it may end up being more trouble than it is worth, since you need to add a lot of checks in place to make sure the resources are in the process of being loaded or if the resource load has in fact failed.

Comment: Thankyou! I guess I wont be doing multi-threading.  Though I will be trying out object pooling.  Thanks much!